# Calculate area covered on map

Tags: ios, math, mkmapview

i'm working on an app that contains a map. Over the map there is a circle that should resemble the covered area in miles. The circle doesn't move around, however the map does move behind it as the user drags it. I want to be able to calculate the area covered by the circle on the map even if the user zoomed in or out. I know it's all mathematical. As an example to what i was talking about, check the app RadPad. Anyway, here is what i have done so far:

1. Calculate the zoom level (as it is needed when user zooms in/out):

   ```
   - (NSUInteger) zoomLevel:(MKMapView*)map 
   {
       return (21 + round(log2(map.region.span.longitudeDelta * MERCATOR_RADIUS * M_PI / (180.0 * map.bounds.size.width))));
   }
   ```
2. In mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated i entered the following:

   ```
   // Place a single pin

   MKPointAnnotation *annotation2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];


   [annotation2 setCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mapView.region.center.latitude, mapView.region.center.longitude-(0.0255*([self zoomLevel:mapView]/12)))];

   [_map addAnnotation:annotation2];
   ```

The annotation is used in order to see if i can locate a point on the circumference of the circle.

running this code works fine on default, however when i zoom in / out the annotation is placed inside the circle or somewhere it shouldn't be.

failing to locate a point on the circle will be an obstacle for me to even calculate the area covered. Any help? hint?

Comment: i may be wrong (do not use your platform) but what is log2 doing in zoom level ? should not be zoom just ratio between real and projected size ?  1.0 -> 100% , 2.0 -> 200%

Comment: Do you really need the area (as in square miles) or just the radius of the circle?